# How to add ImplicitNamingStrategy from auto-configuration class

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I have an auto-configuration class (declared via spring.factories org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration) in a common base project that is used by micro-service projects. I would like to provide an ImplicitNamingStrategy implementation so that projects that use this base project get it automatically.

I tried adding...

```
@Bean
public ImplicitNamingStrategy provideImplicitNamingStrategy()
{
    return CommonApiImplicitNamingStrategy.INSTANCE;
}
```

... but I then got this:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: At least one JPA metamodel must be present!
```

If I remove the bean declaration from the base project's auto-configure class and stick it into the final project's Application class it works as expected. But I don't want to have the the micro-service implementor's add it to each project. I want it included automatically from the base project.

How can I do this?